# Visual Studio 2012 as custom .NET language IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am vaguely aware that visual studio is build as language modules on top of a language agnostic "code editing IDE" base, and that it is possible to extend it to be used as an IDE for other languages.

Would I would ideally like to have, is a new (.net compatible) language and project type that I can have side by side with other projects inside a visual studio solution.

Could anyone help me understand the steps involved / areas of work that need to be done, in order for this to be possible?

Comment: You want the VS Shell. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668 And also Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939841/what-is-the-visual-studio-shell-standalone-shell-good-for

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered. Voting to close.