# Is there any Delphi Open Source project that Implement a basic IDE structure?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have written a framework for Android and Windows, and got some tool that draw the forms and scripting that run on both enviroments. Just another solution like thousands.

What I want to do now is using Delphi (Xe2 in my case) to write an IDE like Delphi itself. That I could manage source files in a project and have forms. I have much of it already on DevExpress components. But I was wondering if there is anything that I could reuse to not invent the wheel again.

Certanly the drawing form should be necessary to have changes for my particular case, however it being capable of drawing forms with buttons, text, those common controls we find in majority of the platforms.

Right now I am using Balsamiq Mockup to draw and export xml to my compiler to integrate on the framework, it is nice, because it is a great drawing product, howeve there is a need to have all that IDE properties integrated and the need to put events on each control, for that an IDE all in one solution is better.

[TMS Scripter](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudiopro.asp) -> I have found this commercial package, that comes with basically everything I need, scripting (I need VB but with different flavor, I believe it could be changed), form designer, project management, etc... It is very nice indeed. However I would like to hear of open source solutions

Comment: Are you looking for an entire IDE, or are you just looking for a form designer?

Comment: I am going more on the direction of an entire IDE, however depends, a good form designer with delphi source code is always a start for the rest of the IDE.

Comment: So you want some kind of "framework" for building IDEs. If you make a list of the things that should be product-specific and which parts are generic and should be provided by the framework, the logical conclusion is that you end up defining Eclipse. Write a plug-in for that.

Comment: I did not realize that Eclipse was a generic IDE, I used to see it related to Java only, but there is even COBOL for eclipse. Very interesting that. Eventually it is something better than building from ground up. Good one.

Comment: Why Delphi? I'd look at extending Eclipse or VS or some other modular IDE.

Comment: Well, My first idea was to get a IDE source code written on Delphi (that is my prefered language) and change it to support the VB script engine that I have already running on Android and Windows. (and eventually something else that is not the way is needed). At first glance I am not planning to sell this IDE, but wanted to have something more professional even for inhouse solution. I came to this forum to expand the possibilities!

Comment: In this situation I'd be favouring the code/project over the language. I wouldn't care too much what the language was, if the IDE was really good.

Comment: Do you already have your compiler or interpreter written or do you mean "I need an interpreter or compiler too".

Comment: it is not mine, however I have an interpreter written on java that is a library of B4A (a vb to java android native code compiler), and the author gave me access to the windows source code (c# that is now a COM) to be used on the Windows and run the same scripting. I am now capable of writing the same business logic using a framework i have created on both platforms.

Comment: IF your interpreter is already written in Java then I would go with Eclipse for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Delphi Open Source IDE, but I think it is free for use and feature rich:
[MS Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb685691.aspx)
[what-is-the-visual-studio-shell-standalone-shell-good-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939841/what-is-the-visual-studio-shell-standalone-shell-good-for)

RemObject use it for there tools. So it fits also for Delphi.

Answer (score 7):

How about Lazarus?  I think that's free, and it certainly has an extensive IDE.
http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/

Comment: I know nothing about lazarus, unless what I read eventually as a clone of delphi. Do you have any clue of the "modularity" of the interface of lazarus and the possibility of extract part of it? I am going to use a vb script, so no delphi at all. However other concepts are the same.

Comment: Chris, can you explain how Lazarus could be of use. It's an IDE dedicated to FreePascal. It appears to be unrelated to question, as I understand it.

Comment: The question is pretty open ended. This is one possible answer. Lazarus is written in itself.  The OP is being kind of vague. Maybe they might like Lazarus and decide to go with it.

Comment: @David at least Lazarus/CodeTyphon is more on-topic than Eclipse and VisualStudio that you suggest

Comment: @Arioch'The That comment suggests that you don't understand the topic.